# object's Scope in switch statement

Tags: c++, pointers, object, switch-statement

I trying to make a program where you have a menu to leave comments, view comments, and create an account. The I made the menu to be a switch statement. In most of the cases I need a "user object", but that is created in case1 and it's scope is only in to case1. I used a "User pointer" so I can use it in the other cases. I have the switch statement so the it runs until the user exits.  When I add the pointer in case1 and ran the program it crashed.     "My question is there another way to have an "user object created in case1 " be accessible to all the other cases ??

```
  User *uPointr = NULL;     


 int: selec;
 cout << " enter a selection: " ;

 do{
 switch(selec)
 {
  case 1: // creates  a user
   {
     string name;
     cout << " Enter you name ": ;
     cin >> name;

     User newUser();    // making an new user 
     addUsertoList(newUser);
     *uPointer = newUser();
      break;
   }

   case 2:
  {
    string message;
    count << " Enter message:;
    cin >> message;

    uPointer.addMessage(message);
     break; 

    }
   case 3:
   {
    UPointer->disPlayMessage();
    break;
    }
    case 4:
   {
    exit(0); 
   }

 }
 } While(1);
```

Comment: There are a lot of things that are wrong with this code. First off, you use `selec` uninitialized, which is undefined behavior. The declaration of `selec` is wrong (this is not Pascal...). `User newUser();` does not create a User object, it declares a function returning a `User`. `*uPointer = newUser()` will try to call that non-existent function and store its return value in the object pointed by `uPointer` which is a null pointer, invoking UB again.

Comment: _"User newUser();    // making an new user"_ Nope.

Comment: You ask the User for the *name*, but you don't do anything with the name.  This is not good, to ask User for information that won't be processed.

Comment: Also, if you are going to use pointer, use them correctly.  The '.' operator is used with instances, the '->' operator is used with pointers.  Most of the time, you don't need to allocate memory with the `new` operator.

Comment: Typos. The C++ language is case sensitive.  There is a difference between `While` and `while`.  The former is not a keyword.  Also, `UPointer`, `uPointer`, `uPointr` are *different* identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Rather you can use std::list containing pointers to User objects outside switch. And then you can insert new user in case 1( like you are doing addUsertoList(newUser) ), modify that user in case 2,3 ...etc.